# How to switch from public to private

Tags: ansible

```
- name: Search1
  become: no   
  delegate_to: localhost   
  command: "../home/ev/search.py {{ item }}"   
  register: name   
  with_items: "{{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|ipaddr('public') }}"   
  changed_when: false
```

I have tried to execute above playbook to our inventory and only worked on servers that has public ip but it didn't on the ones such as VPS/AWS where they have private ip defined on their interfaces.

Is there a way to say if host has private ip then use this:

```
- name: Search2
  become: no   
  delegate_to: localhost   
  command: "../home/ev/search.py {{ item }}"   
  register: name   
  with_items: "{{INVENTORY_HOSTNAME|ipaddr('public') }}"   
  changed_when: false
```

Comment: probably using a VPN or a bastion host could help more

Comment: Can't we just put a when: ansible_interface private ip then use Search2 anything else use Search1? How can we write something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to switch between interfaces using when: ansible_interface|length > 5.
I have many servers with more than 5 interfaces + bonding. 
I had only 1 private interfaces on servers.